# PostgreSQL 9 'pgstats wait timeout' problem

Tags: postgresql, windows

I'm asking about this here because in the PostgreSQL mailing lists no one answered me.
In one of my servers (Windows 2008 R2 Standard/PostgreSQL 9.0.5 64 bits) the logs are being flooded with the following message:

```
2012-03-26 00:00:11 BRT AVISO:  pgstat wait timeout
2012-03-26 00:00:19 BRT AVISO:  pgstat wait timeout
2012-03-26 00:00:31 BRT AVISO:  pgstat wait timeout
```

I checked other threads in the PostgreSQL mailing lists that were answered, but there are no definitive answer. Some speculate about I/O overload, but I don't think it would cause this message to be logged almost all the time that the server is up.
Do you, that use the combination of Windows+Postgresql, have ever had this problem? If yes, were you able to fix or identify the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I've had the problem. Rebooting the db server solved it, at least for a while. I'm in the same boat as you, trying to find an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Reloading the config makes the errors go away, and performance improves (and db statistics start getting recorded again).

I've set up a Windows Scheduled Task which performs a pg_ctl reload -D"insert here the address of your pg directory" on the hour (we're running an incredibly busy application). Hacky, but it's working.

Comment: Hi Scott. The cause of this problem remains a mystery. There's [patch] (http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=79b2ee20c8a041a85dd230c4e787bef22edae57b#patch1) that was to be included in version 9.2 of PostgreSQL. It can help identify the problem, but I didn't had the time to test.